# Django - Sum related fields that belongs to the same FK, for every object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So I'm trying to get the sum of every score in all games related to the according player and how many game he has played

```
class Player(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField()

class Game(models.Model):
     points = models.IntegerField()
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My desired output is:

```
{
    "name": "asdf",
    "total_points": "9999"
    "games_played": "12"
}
```

I thought I could do it getting a value list of my players then looking the sum of all games and count games played for every value on the list, but I don't know how to do it.

I know how to do it for an specific Player, but I want to get the entire list. I see this as a loop where every Player counts by its own.

Thanks

Comment: Is `Game.user` supposed to be a FK to a `Player` rather than a `User`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `models.py` seems like incomplete, So I'm assuming a there is a FK relationship between `Player` and `Game` as below

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Game(models.Model):
    points = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You can fetch all summary of your DB by using a `Group By` query as below,

```
from django.db.models import Count, Sum, F

Game.objects.annotate(name=F('user__name')).values('name').annotate(games_played=Count('id'), total_points=Sum('points'))
```

Sample output will be like this,

```
 <QuerySet [{'name': 'name_1', 'games_played': 2, 'total_points': 6}, {'name': 'name_2', 'games_played': 1, 'total_points': 2}]>
```

`QuerySet` is a iterable similar to `list`. You can iterate over it if you want. Hence each of the item from the `QuerySet` be like this,

```
{'name': 'name_1', 'games_played': 2, 'total_points': 6}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `Player` has a `User` stored as `.user`, you could do something like:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

games = Game.objects.filter(user=player.user)
output = {
    'name': player.name,
    'total_points': games.aggregate(Sum('points')),
    'total_games': games.count()
}
```